# AWS S3 - Athena without gz compression

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm creating a table with the following statement in AWS Athena:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
WITH 
(
  format='JSON',
  external_location='s3://bucket/path'
) AS
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
FROM table1
ORDER BY field1, field2
```

However, when I look into external_location, I see that all the files are compressed into gz format. Is it possible to turn off compression? That is, just write raw JSON to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Athena beyond the basics](https://northbaysolutions.com/blog/athena-beyond-the-basics-part-2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently not possible to create uncompressed files with Athena's CTAS feature. For ORC and Parquet you can choose the compression type, but for all other formats gzip will be used whether you like it or not.

It's a bit ironic that while you can't get CTAS output uncompressed, there is no way to get regular query output compressed.

Comment: As of February 2022, the *default* compression for both the text file and JSON formats is still GZIP and there is not option to not use compression.
However, you can specify the 'write_compression' as ZSTD, SNAPPY, GZIP and BZIP2 for **JSON**, TSV, CSV  and custom SerDes for text. 

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html

Comment: It seems possible now, since May 2022 at least, to specify:
write_compression = 'NONE'
as TBL_PROPERTIES.

Comment: write_compression = 'NONE' as TBL_PROPERTIES

Answer (score 5):

Since ~May 2022 (I didn't see any announcements about this...), you are able to disable the compression.
You need to specify the `write_compression` in the TBL_PROPERTIES / WITH part of the query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (write_compression = 'NONE', format = 'TEXTFILE')
AS SELECT ...
```

All compressions (including 'NONE') per formats are availables here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html

Comment: I just tested write_compression = 'NONE' is working.